# Easiest way to combine 'l','e','t','t','e','r','s'? C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have a string similar to

```
'l','e','t','t','e','r','s'
```

or

```
('l','e','t','t','e','r','s')
```

I know this should be very easy but i dont know how. I know replacing `'` and `,` with "" is an option since both are illegal characters in the result string but i feel theres a better way to do this.

What is the easist way in C# .NET

Comment: Is this a string with this content: `"'l','e','t','t','e','r','s'"`, or is this a byte array?

Comment: iterate the characters and 'take' every 4th character starting from index x where x is determined by if the sequence starts with '(' ?

Comment: oh easiest? I thought you wanted needlessly clever.. easiest is absolutely using replacement/regex.

Comment: I thought a CSV would be available for this type of thing... why is everything telling me to use regex!

Answer (score 10):

That depends what exactly your input-format is.

If you have a string which looks like this, you can either use a chained-Replace:

```
result = "('l','e','t','t','e','r','s')".Replace("(", String.Empty).Replace("'", String.Empty);
```

or Regular Expressions to remove everything you did not want (in this case everything that is not a lower or uppercase letter:

```
result = RegEx.Replace("('l','e','t','t','e','r','s')", "[^a-zA-Z]+", String.Empty);
```

Even easier is to use one of the Constructors of the String, which accepts Character-Arrays:

```
result = new String(new Char[] {'l','e','t','t','e','r','s'});
```

Comment: I think you have an extra caret in your second option (the RegEx) there.

Comment: Remove the `^` (or carets will stay in the string) and change the `*` to `+` (or the regex will "match" on every position in the string since it matches zero-length values.)

Comment: @Sixten Otto, BlixT: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless performance is critical, you're probably best of just using simple replacement. The shortest replacement you can write is something along the lines of:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "\W+", "");
```

Note that `\W` will not remove underscores or numbers. For keeping English letters only, you would use:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

Comment: About performance: your code should be *pretty* efficient. Don’t underestimate regular expressions.

Comment: True =) Even worse is over-estimating them though ;) It wouldn't be too hard to write some 20 lines of code that will be 10 times faster than the regular expression (although with a pre-compiled regular expression maybe it would only be 3-5 times slower than a custom solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think just doing a replace of '/, characters with "" is the best solution, but if you like needlessly complicating things for the sake of premature optimization you could do a regex match on alphabetic characters and then concatenate all the matches together.

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegEx (System.Text.RegularExpressions).

it seems you want to strip out only the alphabetic characters

```
public static string StripNonAlphabets(string input)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex("[^A-Za-z]");

    return reg.Replace(str, string.Empty);
}
```

this method should return what you're looking for